Next API route / Sanity - Navigation call won't update with new data
import { client } from "@/lib/sanity";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

async function fetchData(query) {
  return await client.fetch(query);
}

const queries = {
  fleet: `
    *[_type == "fleet"] {
      title,
      category,
      "slug": slug.current,
    }`,
  training: `
    *[_type == "training"] {
      title,
      category,
      shortTitle,
      "slug": slug.current,
    }`,
  flights: `
    *[_type == "flights"] {
      title,
      category,
      shortTitle,
      "slug": slug.current,
    }`,
  about: `
    *[_type == "about"] {
      title,
      "slug": slug.current,
    }`,
  legal: `
    *[_type == "legal"] {
      title,
      "slug": slug.current,
    }`,
  industry: `
    *[_type == "industry"] {
      title,
      "slug": slug.current,
    }`,
};
export async function GET() {
  try {
    const data = await Promise.all([
      fetchData(queries.fleet),
      fetchData(queries.training),
      fetchData(queries.flights),
      fetchData(queries.about),
      fetchData(queries.legal),
      fetchData(queries.industry),
    ]);
    return NextResponse.json({
      fleet: data[0],
      training: data[1],
      flights: data[2],
      about: data[3],
      legal: data[4],
      industry: data[5],
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch data:", error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Failed to fetch data" },
      { status: 500 },
    );
  }
}

Aplogies I am new to next/sanity. Iv'e put my sanity navigation data into this next API.
However, when I update the menu items in Sanity CMS the API doesn't update... I think its cached? How to fix?
This is how I'm calling it on FE:
async function getNavigationData() {
    let data: any;

    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            `${process?.env?.CURRENT_URL}/api/navigation`,
            { cache: "no-store" },
        );
        data = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch navigation data:", error);
    }

    return data;
}

